# Overflow error in piecewise lambda function

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am writing a piecewise function for a custom ODE solver with numpy.

I want to have an exponentially decaying function, however before some time `t0` I want the function to be identically zero. Here is some sample code that does what I want

```
t0 = 50.0
myF = lambda t:  np.piecewise(float(t), [t<t0, t>=t0],[0, math.pow( math.e ,-(t-t0) ) ] )
print myF(0)
```

however if I make `t0=1000` I get a overflow error

```
t0 = 1000.0
myF = lambda t:  np.piecewise(float(t), [t<t0, t>=t0],[0, math.pow( math.e ,-(t-t0) ) ] )
print myF(0)
```

I assumed that if I made it the function piecewise it wouldn't call the expression if the condition wasn't true. However, It seems that it does. Is there anyway that I can prevent this and not have a overflow error stop my code from running?

**Edit for clarity**: When I call this lambda function It seems to call both conditions at the same time, both '0' and 'math.e ,-(t-t0)' and then only return the '0'. The problem is when 't0= 1000' the value is overflowed when 't = 0'. I want to be able to call 't =0' without the overflow error.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `t < t0` and not `t < 0` by any chance? Because otherwise `t = 0` does not satisfy either of the two conditions in your piecewise definition...

Comment: FYI: Instead of `math.pow( math.e ,-(t-t0) )`, you should use `math.exp(-(t - t0))`; see [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.exp)

Comment: @Praveen, Yes Actually it should be,  't <t0' not 't<0'. however this still does not solve my problem unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like that:

```
t0 = 1000.0;
myF = lambda t: 0.0 if t<0.0001 else math.pow( math.e ,-(t-t0) ) 
print(myF(0))
```

Note that I changed your 0 to 0.0001, as your input does not satisfy any of the conditions [t<0, t>=t0] (because you don't have 0<0).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but my condition was supposed to be 't<t0'. However fixing this does not fix the overflow error. unfortuantly when i change '0.0001' to '1000' I still get the overflow error as in my example

Comment: What if you run the answer I provided (with t0 instead of 0.0001)? I tried it on both python2 and python3 and it worked for me...

Comment: I've played around with your code and it works now! even with, 't<t_0'.  I am still curious why my code fails. But yours works so I'll go with your solution. Thanks so much